# C# RDP not connecting after forloop

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, rdp

I am currently using Microsoft Terminal Services Client what works amazingly and does what i want it to do. But i have ran into a small issue what is proving to be difficult to fix. I am trying to connect to the rdp and then constantly scan if a file exist. But when i do the for loop (After it call the rdp to connect) it doesn't connect. Here is my code:

```
                axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.Server = "0.0.0.0";
                axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.UserName = "Test";
                IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.GetOcx();
                secured.ClearTextPassword = "c";
                axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.Connect();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                for(; ; )
                {
                    if (File.Exists(b + "t.txt"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("File Exists");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a loop to poll for the existence of the file, that's what `FileSystemWatcher` is for.  You'll need to do something like this.

```
var watcher= new FileSystemWatcher(b);
watcher.Filter = "t.txt";
watcher.Created += (sender, eventArgs) => MessageBox.Show("File Exists");
```

I've made some assumptions about what's in your `b` variable, but the point is, the watcher will watch a directory for changes, set the filter for the types of files you're looking for (it will accept wildcards).

If you want to prevent the program from exiting, don't use an infinite loop, just use `Console.ReadKey` or `Console.ReadLine` so you're not doing a busy wait.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your sir saved me! Thank you very much. I didnt know this was a method.. Thanks!

Comment: Line 3 is saying isnt working, "A local parameter named "e" cannot be declared"

Comment: Hmmm, I'd guess you might already have a variable named `e`, I've renamed it in the example code, but any other name will do, as long as it doesn't clash with an existing variable.

Comment: Now im getting sender cannot be declared. Im sorry for bugging you so much but really appreciate the help

Comment: You'll need to rename that variable too, they're not used, so any unique name will do.

Comment: If your version of C# supports it, you can use discard parameters and just declare them as `(_, _)`

Comment: Ive updated my question because when using filesystemwatcher i run into a new error. Please re-check my question above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the for loops affect connection. But, you are creating an infinite loop which does not terminates in any circumstance. Which means you are blocking the Executing thread.

Comment: When i remove the forloop it works perfectly, Thats what i dont understand... And the forloop is after i connect what is strange

Comment: I explained to you, you are blocking thread with infinite loop.

Comment: But the thread is before the infinite loop so shouldn't it execute that first? Also is there a way i can prevent the thread from blocking?

Comment: You are not opening thread. You are in the same thread. So the code starts executing rdp then you get into infinite loop

Comment: I tried adding a thread.sleep(2000) That didnt combat the issue. Do you have any suggestions?